# How can I split up my serverless.yml file into multiple files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using the Serverless Framework for my AWS-powered application. I've been writing a super-long `serverless.yml` file so far, which contains all my lambda code, resources, IAM roles, and State Machines. T find it very hard to manage this big file. How can I work around this? Is there any way to split my `serverless.yml` file into smaller, manageable chunks? It'd be awesome if I can get one `yml` per `lambda`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of Googling, I've finally found something useful!

https://www.serverless.com/blog/structuring-a-real-world-serverless-app

Answer (score 0):

You **can** have one file per lambda, just follow the official [serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#configuration), scroll down to the word "separate" (*or, here is my copy-paste , docs from 2024*):

```yaml
# serverless.yml
---
functions:
  - ${file(./foo-functions.yml)}
  - ${file(./bar-functions.yml)}
```

and "lambda" file:

```yaml
    
# foo-functions.yml
getFoo:
  handler: handler.foo
deleteFoo:
  handler: handler.foo
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could separate your project into services. Then, inside of each service, you can define one `serverless.yml`. You can see the best explanation here:

[Serverless Framework - Documentation: Services](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services)

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking for this on google and found this post. Also I find a youtube video that explain really well how to split a serverless file.

[Split Serverless Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJIN94XVpD0)

I hope it really helps to someone who looks for this in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34552274)

Comment: be careful - the link is a 10min youtube video (I didn't expect it here). Please, share the answer after watching it, thanks!